# CardView Android studio y Spinner

Tags: java, android

Hola amigos tengo un problema con el cardview y un spinner de cantidades del 1 al 10

por ejemplo:
El numero de cardview son 17 
selecciono un numero del spinner y se pone correctamente y cuando hago el scroll 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se selecciona la cantidad del spinner en el cardview #6
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna sugerencia para solucionar el problema???

```
 public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        codigo  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
        titulo  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_titulo);
        precio  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_precio_val);
        cod_prod= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_cod_prod);
        recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        cantidad_s  =   (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.cantidad_spi);
        String []cantidades={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cantidades);
        cantidad_s.setAdapter(adapter);
        cantidad_s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("Items del detalle", String.valueOf(items.size()));
                if(detall.isEmpty()) {
                    detall.add(new Detalles(cantidad_s.getSelectedItem().toString(), codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), cod_prod.getText().toString()));
                }else{
                    int aux=0;
                    for (int x=0; x<detall.size(); x++){
                        if(detall.get(x).getCodigo().equals(codigo.getText())){
                            detall.set(x,new Detalles(cantidad_s.getSelectedItem().toString(), codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), cod_prod.getText().toString()));
                            aux++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(aux==0) {
                        detall.add(new Detalles(cantidad_s.getSelectedItem().toString(), codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), cod_prod.getText().toString()));
                    }
                 }

                //IMPRIMIR TOTAL DE LOS RUBROS
                contTotal=0;
                for (int y=0; y<detall.size(); y++){
                    contTotal=contTotal+(Double.parseDouble(detall.get(y).getCantidad())*Double.parseDouble(detall.get(y).getPrecio()));
                    total.setText(String.valueOf(contTotal));
                }

                for (int x=0 ; x<detall.size(); x++){
                    if(detall.get(x).getCantidad().equals("0")){

                    }else{
                        Log.e("COL_LIB",detall.get(x).getCodigo()+"@@"+detall.get(x).getCod_prod()+"@@"+detall.get(x).getPrecio()+"@@"+detall.get(x).getCantidad());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Me parece que te falta usar `notifyDataSetChanged` para actualizar los cambios, mirate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema precisamente con el reciclado, prueba a desactivarlo.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ManşetViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
}
```